# how to map custom sql query to model to load on jsp view in spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I am beginner in spring. I want to show SQL data to JSP view page.

This is my SQL table

```
    create table customer(
    id int primary key,
    name varchar(250),
    salary int,
    manager_id int
)
```

and I am trying to show data from this query

```
select m.id, m.name, m.salary, n.name from customer m, customer n where n.id=m.manager_id
```

So basically from this query, I am trying to show ID int, name varchar, salary int, manager_name varchar.

I have create the entity java class as below

```
@Entity
@Table(name="customer")
public class Customer{
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private int id;
    
    @Column
    private String name;
    
    @Column(name="manager_id")
    private String manager;
    
    @Column(name="salary")
    private int salary;
    
    ............
    ............
}
```

This is the code of my DAO class

```
    Session session= entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
    Query<Employee> query= session.createQuery(<above sql query need to add here?>,Customer.class);
    return query.getResultList();
```

So the issues are,

1. This SQL query return the data which could not be matched to Customer Entity class. So do I need to create another Entity class for this? Is there any better way?
2. The above required SQL query is not able to execute. What the correct way to execute custom SQL query?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your first question: Yes there is better way. you can directly fetch the results in a projection dto class. take a at: https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-projection-query-to-a-dto-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

About your second question: What Do you mean by saying the query does not execute?
Can you give us the Exception/Stacktrace? Did you try to execute the query (sql form of it) physically? Does it run then?